# Javascript seems to skip the asynchronous parts of my function

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I don't entirely know what I'm doing, so sorry if this is a dumb question, but I've tried to fix this, and I haven't made progress on this damn async. I'm trying to make a scraper to make my own word frequency list, just for the hell of it, and I'm trying to collect links to pages off of pages. Here's the revised code:

```
async function linkChain (depth, already) {
    if (!depth) { return; }
    let promises = [];
    let length = links.length;
    for (already; already < length; already++) {
        promises.push(
            axios.get(www + links[already]).then(response => {
                // (some stuff where I push to links)
                console.log(links.length); // (It's working)
            })
        );
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        linkChain(depth - 1, already);
    });
}

async function run () {
    await linkChain(2, 0);
    console.log("here");
}

run();
```

The cheerio and axios stuff is fixed and working. Links is growing close to a million. But before links.length is console.logged, the console logs "here".

I've tried using .then.catch instead of await and async, I've tried a lot of stuff that was dumb, I've tried searching Stack Overflow (although I may have missed a solution, I'm not familiar with the website).

I have removed some extraneous returns; I thought they might help, and when they didn't I tried something else and forgot to remove them. Some of the dumb stuff.

Comment: `linkChain` does not return anything

Comment: await Promise.all

Comment: Thanks. The bottom of linkChain is now "await Promise.all(promises); await linkChain(depth - 1, already);" and it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`linkChain` doesn't return anything - and you've marked it `async` without ever `await`ing anything which is kinda pointless.

So, either `await Promise.all` or return it (without the `async` keyword). You should also make sure that you return the inner `linkChain` call by either using return statement or removing the braces.

1.

```
async function linkChain (depth, already) {
...
   await Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
       return linkChain(depth - 1, already);
   });
}
```

or

```
async function linkChain (depth, already) {
    ...
    await Promise.all(promises).then(() => linkChain(depth - 1, already));
}
```

2. 

```
function linkChain (depth, already) {
   ...
   return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        return linkChain(depth - 1, already);
    });
}
```

or

```
function linkChain (depth, already) {
   ...
   return Promise.all(promises).then(() => linkChain(depth - 1, already));
}
```